# Is there a USB pedal solution for transcription?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound, remote-control

For transcription it can be useful to use a pedal to control playback of an audio stream so you don't have to stop typing.

Are there any combinations hardware and software that work under Ubuntu for this?

(My personal ideal would be to get a USB pedal to trigger scripts that make API calls to VLC or something, but I'd settle for just about anything!)

Comment: no idea about hard/software combination, but rather than API calls I would try to just emulate the pause button of a multimedia keyboard. this should get forwarded to VLC correctly (or to other software if you decide to switch playback application)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any pre-built pedals right off hand, but I did see this tutorial on how to build your own USB pedal.  Since it is just a modified USB keyboard, it would work fine on linux as well.  You could just assign the keyboard command you chose for the pedal to VLC or whatever playback software you are using.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3NxQ60E72k

Comment: btw its also on make magazines miro channel